# Atomic transactions in DRF action?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get into `Django atomic transactions` at first time. I wonder if there is a possibility to use it something like this:

```
class TaskViewSet(MultiSerializerViewSet):
    @transaction.atomic
    @action(methods=['PATCH'], detail=True)
    def move_task(self, request, pk):
        # making queries, trying to update them, roll back if last one fails.    
        return Response("message: SUCCESS", status=_status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I have searched a bit - there is some information about how to use transactions but I did not find any info if it is possible to use them with DRF.

Comment: the answer is yes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class PayViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    @action(methods=['PATCH'], detail=True)
    @transaction.atomic
    def approval(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        sid = transaction.savepoint()
        success = something 
        if success:
            transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
            return success_response('yes')
        else:
            transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
            return error_response('no')
```

savepoint is optionally depending on your situation

Comment: is there any difference which decorator goes first?

Comment: I didn't test it,but i'm sure @transaction.atomic at last will work.

Comment: ok, one more question - `sid = transaction.savepoint()` - should I make a savepoint on the beginning of every method or optionally if I want some updates to pass and some updates to rollback after fail?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to **wrap all API calls and DRF actions** into **transactions** - you can use ([ATOMIC_REQUEST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ATOMIC_REQUESTS)) Django database settings [from Django 1.8]

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        ....
        "ATOMIC_REQUESTS": True,
```

If you use a **custom exception handler** ([DRF Issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2034)) you may need to adjust it like below

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ....
    "EXCEPTION_HANDLER": "api.exceptions.your_exception_handler",
}


import logging
from django.db import IntegrityError
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler, set_rollback


def your_exception_handler(exc, context):
    """
    DRF custom exception handler.  This will allow us to add useful information
    to any exceptions to help out our frontend devs
    """

    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first, to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if not response and isinstance(exc, IntegrityError):
        # https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5760
        if 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint' in str(exc):
            set_rollback()
            msg = "Unique constraint violated: {exc}".format(exc=exc)
            response = Response({"error": True, "content": msg}, status=400)

    if response is None:
        set_rollback()
        logger.exception(exc)
        response = Response({"error": True, "content": str(exc)}, status=500)

    return response
```